# Pass parameters from AJAX jquery to node js

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax

I want to pass a parameter (source_lead) from a function that write in AJAX jquery to another function in the server part that write in node js.
How can I do it ?

AJAX Jquery :

```
$("#importdata").on('click', function () {
    var source_lead = $("#source").val();
    $.get("/import", function (data) {

        $("#message").show().html(data['success']);
    });
});
```

Node JS :

```
}).get('/import', function (req, res, next) {
// var source_lead = fs.readFileSync('source.txt', 'utf-8');
var csvfile = __dirname + "/../public/Tables/leads.csv";
var stream = fs.createReadStream(csvfile);
var products = [];
var csvStream = csv()
    .on("data", function (data) {
        var item = new Product({
            name: data[13],
            age: data[5],
            phone: data[14],
            email: data[15],
            date: data[1],
            // source: source_lead
        });

        item.save(function (error) {
            console.log(item);
            if (error) {
                throw error;
            }
        });

    }).on("end", function () {

    });

stream.pipe(csvStream);
res.json({success: "Data imported successfully.", status: 200});
})
```

Comment: I mean, if you want to pass it on the request, since it's a get, you just have to put it on the url.  `/import?sourceLead=thevalue` or `$.get(url, { sourceLead: theValue }, function(){ ... })`

Answer (score 0):

1) Client side

```
$("#importdata").on('click', function () {
    var source_lead = $("#source").val();
    $.get("/import?source_lead=json", function (data) {

        $("#message").show().html(data['success']);
    });
});
```

2) NodeJs
    ....

```
}).get('/import', function (req, res, next) {
    let source_lead = req.query.source_lead
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `query params` from ajax call and received it into nodejs api `get` endpoint.

Javascript

```
 $.get("/import?data=myData", function (data) {

        $("#message").show().html(data['success']);
    });
```

NodeJS

```
}).get('/import', function (req, res, next) {
var data = req.query.data; // Query param data

....
```